# Most commented post should be the first post in the blog

Tags: wp-query

WordPress default setting is, most recent post is the first post of the blog.

But, I need to "Most commented post should be the first post in the blog". ( Categories page as well as home page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex, the codex is your friend. You have a parameter `orderby` which you can set to order posts by `comment_count`. You can get the complete list of parameters accepted by `orderby` in the codex page about [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

There is no need for any custom query, you can simply just alter the main query with the use of the action hook [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). To order posts by comment count on the home and category pages, you can use the [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) [`is_home`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) and [`is_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) to target the homepage and category pages respectively.

```
add_action ( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) 
{
    if (    !is_admin()
         && $query->is_main_query()
         && (    $query->is_home() 
              || $query->is_category()
            )
    ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'comment_count' );
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

This code should be placed in your functions.php or any file that is related to functions.php, ie, any file used for rendering functionalities like functions.php does

Comment: I am new to WordPress, but I understand the code. Can you please tell where I add this code? or where I chnage the code. Which file I shoud chnage?

Comment: This should go into functions.php. Just make sure it is in between the first opening `<?php` tag and last closing `?>` php tag

Comment: if($query->is_main_query() AND $query->!is_admin() )

Is above line correct?

Comment: Is it giving you an error. I didn't test the code

Comment: Yes. It gives error. then i remove "AND $query->!is_admin()" part. Then it worked. Is it a problem? What is the important of having  "AND $query->!is_admin()" part?

Comment: Sorry about that, will update my answer, it should just be `AND !is_admin()`. It is necessary otherwise you will make these changes to admin category screen as well

Comment: I'm glad I could help. And thanks for pointing that error out. Enjoy :-)

Comment: This is great! I combined this with customizer, I added the select control for the post order and order by, and set `$query->set( 'orderby', get_theme_mod('post_order_by', 'date') );`. Works like a charm. The same goes for post order :)

Comment: @dingo_d Glad to hear this was helpful. I also update the code a bit

Answer (score 1):

WP Query has a comment_count parameter since 2.9.

You can use `'orderby' => 'comment_count'` in your query with other parameters, which list by number of comment count of post

```
$args=array(
  .......
  'orderby' => 'comment_count',
  .....    
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```